# How to set background of table inside of scrollable_window

Tags: widget, gtk, gtk3

I need to display a dynamic number of buttons in a scrollable view.
For this reason, I nest into window->fixed container a scroll_window with a bound table:

```
GtkWidget* CreateServerSelectView()
{
    GtkWidget *fixed;
    fixed = gtk_fixed_new();
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), server_list_new(), 102, 60); // grid
    return fixed;
}

GtkWidget* server_list_new()
{
GtkWidget *scroll_window;
GtkWidget *table;

scroll_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
int servers_count = 10;
table = gtk_table_new (servers_count, 1, TRUE);

gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (scroll_window), 0);
gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scroll_window), GTK_POLICY_NEVER, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
gtk_table_set_row_spacings (GTK_TABLE (table), 2);

int w = 213 + 20;
int h = 200;

gtk_widget_set_size_request(table, w - 30, h);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(scroll_window, w, h);
gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scroll_window), table);

int j = 0;
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < servers_count; i++)
{
      GtkWidget* button;
      button = gtk_button_new_with_label("ASD");
      gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), button, j, j + 1, i, i  + 1);
                                 //i, i+1, j, j+1);
      gtk_widget_show (button);
}
return scroll_window;
}
```

The button appears fine, but how can I change the table's white bacground?
I've tried to modify, override bg for different statuses on different widgets.
I've also overridden the draw signal for all the widgets which just break the signal.

How can I do that?

UPD:

Tried to use style. Looks like that:

```
GtkWidget* CreateServerSelectView(GtkWindow* mainWindow, SERVER_ENTITY_CONTAINER* servers)
{
button = gtk_button_new_with_label("button");
gtk_widget_set_size_request(button, 213, 37);

fixed = gtk_fixed_new();

serverListWidget = create_gtk_scrollable();
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), button, 102, 292);
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), serverListWidget, 102, 60); // grid

foo_setup_css();

gtk_style_context_add_class ( gtk_widget_get_style_context (button), "my_css");
gtk_style_context_add_class ( gtk_widget_get_style_context (serverListWidget), "my_css");
return fixed;
}


void foo_setup_css()
{
GError* error;
GtkCssProvider *provider;
GdkDisplay *display;

GdkScreen *screen;
provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
display = gdk_display_get_default();
screen = gdk_display_get_default_screen(display);
gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen(screen,
    GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider),
    GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(GTK_CSS_PROVIDER(provider),
    ".my_css{ \n"
    "    background-color: green; \n"
    "    color: red; \n"
    "    font: Bold 16; \n"
    "    border-radius: 8px; \n"
    "    background-image: -gtk-gradient \
                            (   linear, \
                                left top, \
                                left bottom, \
                                from (@bg_color), \
                                    color-stop (0.5, darker (@bg_color)), \
                                to (@bg_color)) \
    }\n"
    ,-1, NULL);

if (error)
    {
        int code = error->code;
        int a = 1;
    }
g_object_unref(provider);
}

GtkWidget* create_gtk_scrollable()
{
GtkWidget *scroll_window;
scroll_window = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);

int w = 213 + 20;
int h = 200;

gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy (GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (scroll_window), GTK_POLICY_NEVER, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (scroll_window), 0);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(scroll_window, w, h);
return scroll_window;
}
```

Comment: Late, but: create new CSS with a custom `background-image`? (hints: `gtk_widget_get_style_context()`, `gtk_css_provider_load_from_data()`)

Comment: @andlabs doesnt work for me, unfortunately. Please see UPD section of post. Button somewhat changes, gradient works. Scrollable - no. Also added class for viewport - doesnt work too.